# Qt: why does connect() work only in the main window class?

Tags: c++, qt, events, signals, slots

Here's a simple code that creates a button and assigns a onclick handler:

```
auto btn = new QPushButton("CLICK ME");
connect(btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(btn_Click()));

private slots:
void btn_Click() {
    alert("clicked!");
}
```

It works as it should if called in the main window class. However when I try to do this in a child window, clicking the button does nothing. The child window is shown like this:

```
auto settingsWindow = new SettingsWindow();
settingsWindow->show();
```

I guess it's somehow connected with the receiver object which is now a different window. But how can I make it work?

Comment: Did you forget to include Q_OBJECT in your class definition?

Comment: Most likely it's the `Q_OBJECT` problem. Unless you get error in the console (that it could not connect a signal to a slot)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to be able to declare signals/slots in your own class you should include Q_OBJECT directive in your class:

```
class SettingsWindow {
        Q_OBJECT

        ...
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add a MACRO in class SettingsWindow to enable singal receiving.
Add "Q_OBJECT" like the following.

```
class MainWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
    MainWidget();
....
```

Comment: Even though a similar answer has been posted already: +1 for inheriting from QWidget when using Q_OBJECT, as the macro will not work when not inheriting from QObject or any of its subclasses